# Can not modify email by using spring framework (Mail-Receiving)

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, spring-integration, email

I am working on a project that requires loading incoming emails, process the email that only passed the filtering criteria, in the end mark the email has been SEEN and modify the subject.

There are couple of issues I couldn't figure out:

1. mail-filter-expression is not working for me. I want to find out the mails that has subject start with "AAA" and the sender's email is "BBB@gmail.com".

   Here is my expression:

   "(subject matches '(?i)AAA.*')|(sender matches '(?i).*BBB@gmail.com.*')"
2. The way how to set user defined flag is very slow. I have to load all email from the open folder and find the email that match with the message Id of current reading message. Is there any better and faster way to do this?

spring-context.xml

```
    <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
                                        store-uri="imaps://XXXX:XXXX@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
                                        channel="receiveChannel"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        should-delete-messages="false"
                                        should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                                        java-mail-properties="mailProperties"
                                        mail-filter-expression="(subject matches '(?i)AAA.*')|(sender matches '(?i).*BBB@gmail.com.*')"/>/>

    <bean id="mailReceiver" class="com.mfr.email.EmailReceiver"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="receiveChannel" ref="mailReceiver" method="process"/>
```

EmailReceiver.java

```
public void process(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Got mail match with filter criteria!");
        try {
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            .........

        Folder folder = message.getFolder();
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            String messageId = ((MimeMessage)message).getMessageID();

            Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
            FetchProfile contentsProfile = new FetchProfile();
            contentsProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
            contentsProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
            contentsProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
            folder.fetch(messages, contentsProfile);
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message loopMsg  = messages[i];
                String loopMsgId = ((MimeMessage)loopMsg ).getMessageID();

                if (loopMsgId.equals(messageId)) {
                    Flags processedFlag = new Flags();
                    processedFlag.add(Flags.Flag.ANSWERED);
                    processedFlag.add(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
                    loopMsg.setFlags(processedFlag, true);

                    break;
                }
            }

            folder.expunge();
            folder.close(true);


        } catch (Exception  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you set `mail.debug=true` in your javamail properties to see if that provides any clues.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have set mail.debug=true, but no useful information returned. No exception, no logs when I call mail.saveChanges(); I guess by that time, the folder has been closed, therefor no changes will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The common folder protocols (IMAP, POP3) do not allow you to modify messages.  You can set the SEEN flag with IMAP, although accessing the message will typically set that for you automatically.  Depending on why you're trying to change the Subject, you might be better off setting a user-defined Flag on the message.  If you really need to change the Subject, you'll need to copy the message using the MimeMessage copy constructor, modify the copy, append the copy to the folder, and delete the original.

Also, your code above appears to be using a Message object unrelated to the Folder you're opening.  You shouldn't do that.  Once you close a Folder, all the Message objects from that Folder are invalid.  If you reopen the Folder, you need to get a new Message object corresponding to the message you're dealing with (e.g., by looking it up using the UID of the message).

Comment: Thanks Bill. User-defined Flag is better idea than change the whole subject. But to do so, what's required to make this happen? I tried following code, but still not working. Did I miss anything?              
             Flags processedFlag = new Flags("processed");
             mail.setFlags(processedFlag, true);
             mail.saveChanges();

Comment: Did you fix the other problem I described?  Also, you don't need the saveChanges call.

Comment: Yes, I fixed other problems. Now I am able to set SEEN and user defined flag. I also realize set SEEN flag with IMAP automatically is good idea. But I need to implement the filter rules first by using imap-idle-channel-adapter.mail-filter-expression. How can I write an expression like this: subject start with "Customer inquiry" and sender email is ###@gmail.com. 
Like this? mail-filter-expression="(subject matches '(?i)Customer inquiry.*')(sender matches '(?i).*###@gmail.com.*')"   I am not familiar with the regular expression please help.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you're trying to use an existing message matching and regular expression capability (and thus just need to understand how to write the regular expression), or whether you're trying to create such a thing yourself (and thus need to  understand how to use regular expressions to match fields of a message).  You can do simple matching using the classes in the javax.mail.search package.  It doesn't support regular expressions, because the IMAP protocol doesn't support them, but the advantage is that all the searching is done on the IMAP server.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I have update  my post. I use spring configuration to fulfill email message filter rule.   Spring Integration introduced mail-filter-expression attribute on inbound-channel-adapter and imap-idle-channel-adapter. This attribute allows you to provide an expression which is a combination of SpEL and Regular Expression.